# 'this' returning different object than expected within JS function

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple select box:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="Condiments">
  <option selected="selected">Mustard</option>
  <option selected="selected">Ketchup</option>
</select>
```

and I'm using the jQuery UI MultiSelect Widget to make it a bit spiffier:

https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget

Specifically I'm trying to set one of the options *dynamically* when the widget is initialized.  When I do this:

```
$("select").multiselect({
  selectedText: function(numChecked, numTotal, checkedItems){
    return "Foo";
  }
});
```

it properly sets the selectedText option to "Foo" but when I do this:

```
$("select").multiselect({
  selectedText: function(numChecked, numTotal, checkedItems){
    return $(this).attr("name");
  }
});
```

it think that $(this) is a span from somewhere else in the DOM.

If there were only one select on the page this would be fine, but with multiple i need a way to set this option for each.  Is there an obvious way to get from $(this) to the current select element?  or an obvious alternative to solving the same general problem?

Comment: As the result of $("select"0 is an array in case of multiple selects, the $(this) will point to the globals window object. Use a class or id to specify the select you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in the `selectedText` callback, `this` is the JavaScript object that instruments the multi-select functionality for the `<select>` element. It has an `element` property that is a jQuery object that wraps the `<select>` element.

Therefore you should use:

```
$("select").multiselect({
    selectedText: function(numChecked, numTotal, checkedItems){
        return this.element.attr("name");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A common approach for initializing a plugin on multiple elements that require passing specific data or properties from the element instance that aren't built into the plugin is to loop over the element collection using `each`:

```
$('select').each(function(){
   /* "this" will be instance of "select"*/
  /* prep data needed before initialiizing plugin*/

   var name= this.name;
   /* initialize plugin for current instance of element*/
   $(this).multiselect({
      selectedText: function(numChecked, numTotal, checkedItems){
        /* variable declared above*/
         return name;
       }
    });

});
```

I don't know the particular plugin, or what `this` is within the callback, but using the approach shown it isn't necessary to know as the instance is already isolated within the `each` loop

**Edit.** I wrote this without thinking about plugin being for `<select>` elemnt. Not sure why you would want `name` to be returned.. Would be same for any option selected